# Delegate Instantiation -Clarification

Tags: asp.net, delegates

When i have delegate like

```
public delegate void PrintMe();

(1)
PrintMe a = delegate() { MessageBox.Show("Hello"); };
a();

(2)
PrintMe b = () => { MessageBox.Show("Hello"); };
b();

(3)
PrintMe c = new PrintMe(HelpMe);
c();

static void HelpMe()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Help Me");
}
```

for (1) and (2) I did not instatntiate the delegate it is directly pointing to anonymous methods.But as in the case of (3) I need to instatntiate the delegate and pass the static method.for case (3) can't i declare like  `PrintMe c= HelpMe(); ?`.How does (1) and (2) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PrintMe c = HelpMe;
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the implicit conversion between method groups and delegates you can say

```
(3)
PrintMe c = HelpMe;
```

i.e. without parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

In (1) and (2) the compiler implicitly converts your lambda expression into a delegate.

If you try to do

```
PrintMe c= HelpMe();
```

then you are telling the compiler to generate a call to HelpMe and assign the result of that call to `c`.
Instead, you can do

```
PrintMe c = HelpMe;
```

Here, `HelpMe` occours as what is known as a method group (it is not just *a* method, because it may have overloads), which may be converted to a delegate if at least one method in the group fits the delegate.